# Creating a similar image using CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how I could create a container that would resemble this using only css? maybe the Transform3d properties off CSS3.
Any suggestion, I am really curious to see if that twisted effect can be applied to a rectangle.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use CSS for these kind of shapes/effects. While it may actually be possible, the approach would be very complex and unmaintainable. I'd suggest having a look at SVG/Canvas (preferably SVG).

Comment: Images still have their place too...

Comment: how would one do this in SVG? I want to be able to dynamically set the color and text

Comment: I get that CSS may not be the way to go but I am looking for helpful as to which direction to go into with this??

Comment: Unless you need this effect in ridiculously high-quality (then use SVG), an image without text is the best way to go.  Then just basic CSS positioning to overlay text on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in SVG and keep it dynamic as SVGs are XML.  The simplest solution would be several PNGs of different colors that are switched dynamically.

As for keeping the text dynamic, your image should only be the background, the text can stay in HTML.